# Why does my overflow and text-overflow: ellipsis code not work in MS Edge?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

```html
<ul>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="md_li"><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<style>
  a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but not Edge. I mean it becomes ugly in Edge; I don't mean the ellipsis doesn't work.

How do I make it work in Edge?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKv6Y.png)

---

Well, I change the code like this

maybe vertical-align: top; is better

```html
<ul>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>
 </li>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>
 </li>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>
 </li>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>
 </li>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>
 </li>
 <li class="md_li"><span><a href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span> 
 </li>
</ul>
<style>
span{
 display:inline-block;
 width: 100%; 
}
a{
 width: 90%;  
 padding: 0 !important;  
 margin:0 !important;
 overflow: hidden;  
 display: inline-block;  
 text-decoration: none;  
 text-overflow: ellipsis;  
 white-space: nowrap; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You just need to add display: inline-block; and width to your css code will fix the issue for Edge browser. Example: https://textuploader.com/1dref Output in Edge: https://i.postimg.cc/Znjykdng/14.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-overflow:ellipsis;` is working when below the step following:
The element width has px or % and element have `overflow: hidden` and `white-space:nowrap`.

Please try the code below:

```css
a { 
    width: 140px;  
    padding: 0;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    position: relative;  
    display: inline-block;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**What `version` of `Edge` you are using?** According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow) text-overflow is working fine for `Edge 12 and above`. 
So if you are working with below this version, your code wont work.

Possible workaround this is, just add some width to your parent element like,

```
ul{
   width:50%
}
```

Comment: I mean in edge the li element is getting higher